# Property 'contentForWildcard' has redundant after migrating to Gradle 7.4 from 6.8

Tags: java, gradle, wsdl, xjc

I'm using the gradle-xjc-plugin (Version: 1.4.2) to generate required classes from WSDL. the xjcGenerate task in my gradle worked fine until I migrated the gradle version to 7.4 from 6.8.

```
xjcGenerate {
   targetPackage = "nl.cir.xsd"
   source = fileTree('src/main/resources/wsdl')
   extraArgs = [ '-wsdl' ]
}
```

I'm receiving the following error during task execution...

```
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':cir:xjcGenerate' (type 'XjcGenerate').
  - In plugin 'org.unbroken-dome.xjc' type 'org.unbrokendome.gradle.plugins.xjc.XjcGenerate' property 'contentForWildcard' has redundant getters: 'getContentForWildcard()' and 'isContentForWildcard()'.
```

Would anyone be able to help me to resolve this issue?